# In the new Analyze UI, how do I edit the title of my query?

Tags: qubole

In the new Qubole Analyze UI that came out recently, I cannot seem to find a way to change the title of a command. In the old interface, I could click on the command title and it would become an editable text box.

[image: new UI screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are not planning for the same feature of having to edit command names. But the similar will be available as part of collections feature which is currently work in progress. We will update our release docs as it is ready for release.

Comment: I'm sad to hear that this piece of functionality is being removed. It is extremely helpful and useful when running lots of queries because it makes it easy to give each query a meaningful name for easy identification later.

Comment: @GreenGiant We are not completely going away from the feature of edit command name/title(s). We will be saving the commands to collections kind of grouping based on command title by default which can be renamed or edited.

We would like to invite you to join our beta community group so that you can get previews, and demos of what's coming. Would also love to chat with you to gather specific feedback for this will help us and the broader community of users. You can reach our product manager directly at ranga@qubole.com